# how to add dynamic options using jquery with same class?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn to add category and subcategory dynamically in a dropdown menu with the same class, however when i click the first dropdown all inputs gets effected

html :

```
form action="" method="post">

<div id="tmp"> <select class="category"> <option value="">Select
Category</option>

 </select>

<label>Sub Category</label> <select class="sub_category">

</select>> 
<br></div> <input type="button" id="add" value="Add another"> 
    </form>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()  { 
    var wrapper = $("#tmp"); //Fields wrapper  
    var add_button = $("#add"); //Add button ID  
    var pfield = "<label>Category</label>"+ 
    "<select class=\"category\">"+  
    "<option value=\"\">Select Category</option></select>"+  
    "<label>Sub Category</label>"+  
    "<select class=\"sub_category\"></select><br>"

    $(add_button).click(function(){ //on add input button click 
        $(wrapper).append(pfield); //add input box

    }); 
});



$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.category').each( function() {

        $(this).on('click', function() {

           for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
              $(".category").append($("<option></option>").attr("value",i).text("something"+i)); 
           } 
         }); 
    }); 
});


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.category').each( function() {

        $(this).on('change', function() {

            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
                $(".sub_category").append($("<option</option>").attr("value",j).text("somethingelse"+j)); 
            }

        }); 
     }); 
 });

</script>
```

Comment: okay, sure.. problem with the code is when i press add another it adds fresh sets of dropdown, but they are getting affected with any change that i make to the first dropdown

Comment: the each() function isn't workin

Comment: I got you a fiddle started - (https://jsfiddle.net/hk59b4d1/), you can modify the code at the jsfiddle until you get the desired results. I can tell you one thing that is wrong is that each time you click on the dropdown for category, you re-add the same options again, I think you only want to add them once. Same goes for the sub_category. I also combined your code into one `$(document).ready()`

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks very much, could you pls. tell me where an i goin wrong?

Comment: Please see provided answer and link to working fiddle below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to help you out and hopefully teach you a few things along the way:

```
$(document).ready(function()  { 
    const wrapper = $("#tmp"); //Fields wrapper  
    const add_button = $("#add"); //Add button ID  
    const pfield = "<label>Category</label>"+ 
    "<select class=\"category\">"+  
    "<option value=\"\">Select Category</option></select>"+  
    "<label>Sub Category</label>"+  
    "<select class=\"sub_category\"></select><br>"

    $(add_button).click(function(){ //on add input button click 
        $(wrapper).append(pfield); //add input box
    });
    
    //***START of updated code***
    //We use Event Delegation in this scenario - 
    //learn more here: (https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
    //We attach the click/change events to the parent div, but delegate it
    //to children of class .category
    
    //Use delegate event handler
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.category', function(){
        //Check to see if the drop down has more than 1 option
        //if not, perform the append of the desired options
        if($(this).find('option').length < 2){
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
                $(this).append($("<option></option>").attr("value",i).text("something"+i)); 
            } 
        }
    });
     //Use delegate event handler
     $(wrapper).on('change', '.category', function(){
         //This one is a little tricky, we only want to check and append
         //to the closest drop down of className .sub_category
         //We can get the closest .sub_category drop down by using
         //.nextAll() - passing a selector of .sub_category and specifying the first match using :first
         //So we check to see if the sibling .sub_category has any options
         //If not, we add them
         if($(this).nextAll('.sub_category:first').find('option').length < 1){
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) { 
                $(this).nextAll('.sub_category:first').append($("<option></option>").attr("value",j).text("somethingelse"+j)); 
            }
         }   
     });
    
    
});
//***END of updated code***
```

Here is a working jsfiddle - (https://jsfiddle.net/jty0716k/2/)

Comment: you're awesome.. works like magic!! thanks very much..

Comment: @John You're welcome. Please take the time to read through the code and my comments as it may help you in your future coding efforts.

Comment: especially for the learning :), thanks for your efforts!!

Comment: @John No problem. We all are learning. That's what it is all about. :)